# @ContributesAndroidInjector on a activity that extends CordovaActivity

Tags: android, dagger-2

According to Dagger's [doc](https://dagger.dev/api/2.12/dagger/android/ContributesAndroidInjector.html) I can use ContributesAndroidInjector on a  concrete Android framework type. I will not be able to extend DaggerActivity as I have a hybrid app and in my case and I am using my activity by extending CordovaActivity. What should be the approach in these scenarios?

Should I fall back to pre 2.10 way of registering the Activity to be injected by Dagger as below on an activity's `onCreate()`.

```
@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ((App)getApplication())
        .getAppComponent()
        .inject(this);
  }
```

By doing this I have to rewrite my Application class to return appComponent which again defeats the purpose of DI.

Can you please guide me in the right path providing some inputs to handle this scenario.

Comment: *which again defeats the purpose of DI.* says who

Comment: I felt "This pattern however breaks a core principle of dependency injection: a class shouldn’t know anything about how it is injected."

Comment: There's no need to extend `DaggerActivity`. Look at its source code. It implements an interface and calls `AndroidInjection.inject(this)`, both of which you can do yourself, too.